# How to install package from testing?

Tags: sync, debian

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server and need a fix for https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vagrant in version `1.8.1+dfsg-2` released for Yakkety, but not for Xenial.

So how to install that `1.8.1+dfsg-2` for Xenial so that it gets replaced with official package once it is released?

UPDATE: Note that I don't want to `pin` the package. I want it to update to the subsequent stable once that stable is released.

Comment: why install vagrant from upstream package repos ? this don't get updated if Vagrant is updated, why not the vagrant*.deb package from https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html ?

Comment: @YonsySolis where do you see that the package is installed from upstream?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I am fine with building as long as it will be replaced with new stable release with bugfix  automatically once that release is out.

Comment: What makes you think 1.8.1+dfsg-2 will be uploaded to Xenial? It is not in Xenial [SRU queue](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/pending-sru.html).

Comment: @AnthonyWong I don't know why Ubuntu guys didn't add it to SRU - it fixes critical bug in vagrant package that breaks plugin installation.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik: Maybe someone should file a bug report for that on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vagrant. Why don't you do it? :-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster doesn't help. =( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vagrant/+bug/1559420

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want the newer package this one time and you also want it to be replaced once the right version is released for your current release of Ubuntu you can:

1. Install the build tools and dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts
   sudo apt-get build-dep vagrant
   ```
2. Download the package source and extract it:

   ```sh
   dget -u https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/vagrant_1.8.1+dfsg-2.dsc
   cd vagrant-1.8.1
   ```
3. Add a changelog entry with a carefully crafted local version suffix (replace `anatoly` and the log message with whatever you want):

   ```sh
   debchange --local=~anatoly 'Backport to Xenial'
   ```

   This will bump the package version to `1.8.1+dfsg-2~anatoly1`. The tilde suffix has the property that it is actually considered as a lower version than `1.8.1+dfsg-2`:

   ```sh
   $ dpkg --compare-versions 1.8.1+dfsg-2~anatoly1 '<' 1.8.1+dfsg-2; echo $?
   0
   ```

   That means the package manager will suggest to “upgrade” the local package once version `1.8.1+dfsg-2` (or newer) becomes available in the configured repositories.
4. Build the binary package:

   ```sh
   debuild -b -j"`getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN`"
   ```
5. Install the built package(s) with `sudo dpkg -i <DEBFILE>...`.

P.S.: I didn't try to build the package myself so you may run into issue. For instance, the source package for Yakkety may depend on a package (version) that isn't in Xenial (less likely at this point and since it's the same upstream version). In that case we can look for ways around this.

Comment: Need some time to test this. I wish I could do this inside container.