# Using bluez-5.43 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth, ps3

Please excuse me this is all virgin territory to me. Right I have Ubuntu 16.04 so I've been installing emus for it snes,nes,mega drive,etc. Well now I want to use my ps3 controller to play them. I got bluez-tools extracted the files but now how would I go about installing it and setting it up to use.Thanks in advance people hope you can help

Answer (score 7):

I needed to install the bluez-5.43 to get around bugs in the default bluez-5.37 when using bluetoothctl from scripts.

You could probably install the binary version from Zesty, but my experience is that you often run into other dependencies.

I just install the deb-src package from Zesty.  You probably need to install other dependencies too, here is what I had to do.

```
sudo  apt-get install debhelper dh-autoreconf flex bison libdbus-glib-1-dev libglib2.0-dev  libcap-ng-dev libudev-dev libreadline-dev libical-dev check dh-systemd libebook1.2-dev

wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/bluez_5.43.orig.tar.xz
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/bluez_5.43-0ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/bluez_5.43-0ubuntu1.dsc

tar xf bluez_5.43.orig.tar.xz
cd bluez-5.43
tar xf ../bluez_5.43-0ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz
debchange --local=~lorenzen 'Backport to Xenial'
debuild -b -j4
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

For an explanation of what is happening here, please consult
https://askubuntu.com/a/771272/655086

Comment: if debuild give an authentication error, try running with arguments "-uc -us" as suggested in http://serverfault.com/questions/191785/how-can-i-properly-sign-a-package-i-modified-and-recompiled

Comment: i also needed `apt-get install devscripts`

Comment: i also needed `gpg --gen-key` for signing

Comment: I also needed to add `-k$GPG_KEY` to the `debuild` command. Where `$GPG_KEY` is the pub key you can find running `gpg --list-key`. Example: `GPG_KEY=${gpg --list-key --with-colons | grep pub | awk -F: '{print $5}'}`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the extracted file (*unless you're installing a particular version or the latest*) as you can install from the repositories with the following command:

```
sudo apt install bluez-tools
```

Now simply use it.